# httpd not showing/using most updated version of apache (via brew)

Tags: apache

I just installed the latest version of Apache (2.4.43) using brew on Mac OS (10.14.5). (Using instructions from [this site](https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-macos-homebrew/).) But after restarting the service, `httpd -v` still shows 2.4.34 running from the Mac OS default. The same old version is shown when I query `apachectl -v`.

Thinking that perhaps I needed to update with one more step, I ran `brew update httpd` but it said that "httpd 2.4.43 already installed."

I'm still pretty new to using brew, and this is my first time creating an Apache server, so any help here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - easy fix. I neglected to update my .bash_profile to include /usr/local/opt/apache2/bin.

This was clear after I ran `which apachectl`, and it displayed the default directory for the preinstalled version of Apache - /usr/sbin/apachectl.

I ended up stopping the default version and prevented it from starting again on boot:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Then, started the newly installed version, and it worked fine.